# How to add evolution to the messaging menu?

Tags: evolution

The item in the messaging menu (`indicator-applet`) related to Evolution program disappeared after reinstalling Evolution. How to I re-add it back?

Answer (score 14):

Install the `evolution-indicator` package.

Answer (score 2):

The evolution-indicator package is no longer present on 12.10. There seems to be no way to use evolution with the messaging menu at the moment.

Comment: You can build the evolution-indicator package yourself (backporting from raring): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12391149#post12391149

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.10 download from http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/evolution-indicator. You may need to (re)start Evolution after installing the package.