# Use evolution instead of thunderbird in top toolbar area

Tags: unity, evolution, indicator-message

Is there any possibility to use evolution instead of thunderbird in the top toolbar area as email client? I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 with Unity. I've installed evolution, I just wanna that I can create an email by clicking on the email icon (see below)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you may need to install the `evolution-indicator` package: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5643/how-to-add-evolution-to-the-messaging-menu see also this Q&A where I said how to remove Thunderbird or any other entry: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449174/email-icons-missing-from-menu-bar-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open a terminal and install the evolution indicator:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install evolution-indicator
   ```
2. Change the default email application in the messaging indicator:

   ```
   dconf write /com/canonical/messages/applications "['evolution.desktop']"
   ```
3. Restart your session, the indicator will look like this:

   [image]